# https server is not working for node js application

Tags: https, node.js

I have a domain with SSL certificate. My default application is running perfect. Now i am running node.js application in another port with SSL i.e. https server. But the server is not running. Here is my sample code.

```
var http = require('http'),
     https = require('https'),
     fs = require('fs'),
     express = require("express");

  var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/abc.com-key.pem",),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/abc.com.pem")
  };
  var app = express(options);

  var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(MY_IP, 9002);
```

Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any  error?